# "Отлынивать"

Tags: этимология

И сразу вопрос вдогонку (пришло в голову, пока писал первый). Говорят еще "отлынивать от работы". Интересует слово "отлынивать".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По смыслу, конечно, смыкается со словами "лениться", "лодырничать", есть здесь и какое-то звуковое соответствие. Впрочем, Фасмер возводит это слово к форме "лытать", которое также означает "лениться", "лодырничать".

А вот последние два слова у Фасмера почему-то не нашла ((

Comment: так надо смотреть на "лень" и "лодырь".

Comment: Свежая мысль! Сама бы я не догадалась! Лодыря не нашла. Лень есть, но ничего интересного. "Смысл не претерпел измененй". Свзи с "лылыть" не указано, только с "лежать".

Comment: Ну вы же говорили, что не нашли вообще.

WORD: ло́дарь 
GENERAL: -я, ло́дырь, укр. ло́дарь -- то же (Преобр.).
ORIGIN: Вероятно, заимств. из ср.-нж.-нем., нж.-нем. lodder, loder; см. Бернекер 1, 735; Кнутссон, GL 27. Формы гло́дарь, гло́дырь -- то же, севск., появились в результате народн. этимологии от глода́ть (Преобр. I, 463). Наряду с этим польск. ɫоtr "подлец, негодяй" -- из нем. lotter; см. Мi. ЕW 174; Бернекер, там же. См. лотры́га.
PAGES: 2,510

Comment: Ну, с лодырем понятно. А все-таки почему "отлынивать" и "лениться" не родственные слова? На вид они довольно похожи.

Comment: Ну навскидку уже потому, что чередование Ы/Е крайне сомнительно.  
DocentI, не надо спрашивать почему. Надо формуоировать гипотезы - и доказывать или опровергать. Меня вопросы с "Почему" вводят в ступор. В 99% случаях на них принципиально невозможно дать правильный ответ либо по сути, либо по форме. Чаще всего -  и то и другое.

Comment: Когда я спрашивала "почему" - я имела в виду именно "фонетическое" обоснование, т.е. какие преобразования возможны в звучании слова.  

А если Вам не нравится вопрос - не отвечайте. Вы что, считаете своим долгом ответить на ВСЕ вопросы форума, даже на комментарии?

Answer (score 0):

сегодня от коллеги из Беларуси услышал - хватит лынды бить. лынды, тоже самое, что и баклуши. может отлынивать - бить те самые лынды?